# Google Cloud Print used to work but now print jobs sent from my Android Tablet always queued

Tags: jquery, html, css, printing, google-cloud-print

I'm working with Google cloud printing. Everything else works just fine. When i give print call from my desktop PC (chrome browser). 
But when i make a print call from my samsung tablet (Chrome browser). It stuck in a queue and not get printed.
Anyone have a solution?

Here is code:

```
  var gadget = new cloudprint.
  gadget.setPrintDocument("text/html", "Sale", MyHtml);
  gadget.openPrintDialog();
```

Comment: Can you please paste a bit of code...?

Comment: added a bit of a code @sebastian